# "Open In" should show my app in iPhones Camera Roll

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, camera-roll, document-types

How can I have my app in the list of apps so that users can share photos to my app. I have tried setting public.png Document Types in Info.plist but it doesn't show up in the list.
Please check the apps encircled in the attached photo, I want my app in that list .

[image: Attachment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use iOS share extension

https://www.appcoda.com/ios8-share-extension-swift/